# Convert base 64 encoded data to binary data with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, base64, decode

When I fire a async call to a server, I receive the base64 data of a PDF file (binary data). I want to convert this base64 data to binary and give the user as a file from browser side. I found downloadify for downloading. But I am still stuck with the part to convert base 64 encoded data to binary data in JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why convert ? ;) Just serve your link as `data:application/pdf;base64,` and then you base64 encoded pdf.

Will not work in old IE, of course. But *should* work in most modern browsers.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

Answer (score 0):

Even if you converted the base64 data to binary in javascript (and I find it extremely strange that a server would even do that - just send the binary data in the first place), you will not be able to generate a download link in javascript.

So there is no point in writing the conversion code.

Have the server send the binary data directly with the proper `Content-Type:` and `Content-Disposition:` headers.

You may even be able to add the `Content-Encoding: base64` header and the browser will convert it on its own.